# Extract text in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have the following in column A1. I'm trying to extract the value that goes after `6922=`, and in some cases before a `pipe |`, or at the end of the line.

So in the four cases below, I would be extracting `MXGB0IN`

I managed to extract it in line 1 and 2 using `LEFT(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=";A2)-4);SEARCH("|";RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=";A2)-4))-1)`. However, in cases 3 and 4, there no pipes at the end.

How can I do this?

Thanks

```
6784=125SF|6922=MXGB0IN|6926=U  
6922=MXGB0IN|6926=U    
6922=MXGB0IN
6993=!ELP|6920=MP|6921=6|6922=MXGB0IN
```

Comment: Have you looked at using TextToColumns delimited on `=` or `|`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFERROR here :

`LEFT(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=";A2)-4);IFERROR(SEARCH("|";RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("6922=";A2)-4))-1; len(A2) ))`